# how to run tsql query in batch -- delete 5000 rows at a time and commit

Tags: sql

Can you please tell me how to run a query in chunks . I AM TRYNING to delete duplicate records based on MyKey. how to tune this"

```
WITH cte AS
 ( SELECT [ID] ,[F2] ,[F3] ,[F8] ,[F14] ,[F29] ,[F31] ,[F43] ,[F44] ,[F45] ,[F46] ,[F47] ,[F48] ,[F49] ,[F50] ,[F52] ,[F53] ,[F54] ,[F55] ,[F56] ,[F57] ,[F58] ,[F59] ,[F63] , row_number() 
OVER(PARTITION BY MyKey ORDER BY MyKey 
) 
AS [rn] 
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] 
) 
DELETE cte WHERE [rn] > 1
```

"

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you want the final query to be:

```
DELETE cte WHERE [rn] > 1 and rn < 5000
```

Do you need help writing a `while` loop as well?

Comment: uh. I think that this would in fact delete almost the same initial rows, unless there are more than 5000 duplicates for a key.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for Replying .  My query is deleting duplicate rows on 500 Million table.  it keeps on running for days.  My records are not duplicated more that 20 . But problem is that it wont commit. I need to write a loop and and insert commit. rn is never  greater than 20. All I need to commit when few duplicated records being deleted. If My query cancelled for some reason, it wont rollback all the deleted records. I do not need duplicated records. I have backup of full table.  Regards